# Pop fragment from backstack and add it again

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments **friendListFragment** and **logListFragment**.

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    FriendListFragment friendListFragment = (FriendListFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.friend_list_fragment_container);
    LogListFragment logListFragment = (LogListFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.log_list_fragment_container);
```

The latter is created in the context of the **onListItemClick** event of the former.

```
    fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    logListFragment = LogListFragment.newInstance(name);
    ft.add(R.id.log_list_fragment_container, logListFragment);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        ft.hide(friendListFragment);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

With every call of **onListItemClick** I clear the backstack first, because I only want to have the latest **logListFragment** on the backstack.

In the **onCreate** function of my activity I take care about the orientation of my phone. In portrait mode I clear the backstack and add the **logListFragment** again in the following way:

```
    if ((logListFragment != null) && (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)) {
        fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        ft.add(R.id.log_list_fragment_container, logListFragment);
        ft.hide(friendListFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

After that the **friendListFragment** is hidden as expected, but also the **logListFragment** isn't visible.
When I change the code the following way it works as expected:

```
    if ((logListFragment != null) && (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)) {
        LogListFragment copy = new LogListFragment();
        copy.setArguments(logListFragment.getArguments());
        fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        ft.add(R.id.log_list_fragment_container, copy); // <- use copy
        ft.hide(friendListFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

When I add a new instance of **LogListFragment** it works.

**Questions**:

1. Why do I need to create a new instance?
2. Does someone know a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

maybe replace fragment is better option?

ft.[replace (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)